# Should I send additional headers with XmlHttpRequest POST?

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache, post, xmlhttprequest

After opening XmlHttpRequest POST connection

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", url, true);
```

[Some](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php) recommend to include these additional headers before sending the request:

```
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

Is it necessary on Apache+PHP server? It works fine on my server without those headers.

Comment: browser automatically add those .but if you are expecting json or xml its good to give headers

Comment: @ArunKillu: you mean in response? Why it is good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code works fine without headers because ,`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is default `post content-type` you can see that in console.but if you are `sending a file` you have to exclusively  set it to `multipart/form-data` then only server accept file.Also if in response if server doesn't send proper headers it becomes impossible to read the type of response from client eg in the case of json response if `APPLICATION/JSON` is needed otherwise it will be interpreted as `text/html` .