# How do I properly use xmlhttprequest to send JSON in body?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, body-parser

I'm trying to send a fairly large amount of JSON to my Node-Express server via xmlhttprequest.  In the past I've been able to pass parameters by encoding them in the url.  The JSON I'm sending is too long to encode in the url so I'm attempting to send it in the body.  So far the body is an empty object.

I've read [mdn's article on xmlhttprequest.send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send).
I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676263/should-i-send-additional-headers-with-xmlhttprequest-post), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376246/unable-to-send-json-object-to-xmlhttprequest), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49597999/post-request-with-xmlhttprequest-javascript) on stack overflow, and the solutions don't resolve my problem.

Here's my client-side code:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var body = {/*a javascript object with data to be sent to server*/};
var uri = 'https://my_internal_corporate_url/endpoint';
var bodyStringified = JSON.stringify(body)
xhr.open('POST', uri, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(bodyStringified);
xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);
function processRequest(e) {
   // do stuff with server response
    }
```

My node-express server receives the request, but I can't find the contents of 'bodystringified' anywhere in the request object, which tells me either I'm not constructing the request object properly or my api is not able to parse the request properly.

I had been thinking I was choosing the wrong content-type in the setRequestHeader method above.  However, I'm beginning to think it's my server not being properly configured to parse the body of the request.

Here's a snippet of my Node-Express code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../.env')
  });
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const queries = require('./controllers/queries');
const os = require('os');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

And a snippet of the endpoint code handling these requests:

```js
const sendData = (data, res, status) => {
    if (status) {
        res.status(status).send(data);
    } else {
        res.send(data);
    }
}

router.post('/rw_json_to_html', (req, res) => {
        console.log('req: ', req); // <-- when I inspect this obj, I can't find my json.
        let data = // do stuff with the json provided in body of req object
        sendData(data, res, 200);
}
```

**QUESTIONS:**
1.  Am I setting the request headers incorrectly or something in the client code? 
2.  Am I missing something in my Node-Express options for properly parsing the body of requests?  Body-parser options for example?  I've used axios in the past and had no issues getting request bodies, but the current application requires me to use plain vanilla javascript in the client.

Thank you so much for reading my post.

Comment: Are you coming from an SSL start point with your code or from standard http?

Comment: Hello @MarcusParsons.  It's https from the client to the load balancer, but http from the load balancer to my Node server.

Comment: You have no end point in that Node code. Where are you trying to look at the request body?

Comment: "Body-parser for example?" — You're using body parser.

Comment: @Quentin I added the endpoint code to my post. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

When I run `console.log('req: ', req);` I get over 800 lines of output, so its no wonder you can't find anything in there.

See [the documentation for body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser):

> ```
> app.use(bodyParser.json())
>
> app.use(function (req, res) {
>   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
>   res.write('you posted:\n')
>   res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
> })
> ```

The decoded JSON appears in `req.body`.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin.  I simply perform a search in my text editor for a keyword in my JSON, which comes up dry.  That's how I overcome that issue.